# Creating a Drag n Drop Designer so users can create a Form?

Tags: winforms, silverlight, drag-and-drop

I'd like to create a way for my users to create Forms so they won't have to ask me to do it. Unfortunately, I am in dark, unknown territory. I envisioned it as the following:

- User can drag pre-made tables or (pre-made) custom rows.

  Once the user has created the layout, he will save the layout and deploy to the server.

  Other users will then be able to access the new Form which will have textboxes, radiobuttons, and checkboxes.

  Lastly, users will be able to save and load that Form Data anytime they access the Form.

Anyone can point me in the right direction or give me a quick summary of what I'll need to accomplish this task? It will be much appreciated.

At this point, I'd like to do it in WinForms, WPF, or Silverlight. I know the tech is different but the overall approach should be same (I'm hoping).

Comment: Why would you want to support both WinForms and WPF??  Remove the WinForms requirement and you will be in much better shape to make this actually happen.

Comment: I said Winforms, WPF, OR Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building an application for form-filling, consider using Microsoft Infopath.

If Infopath is too expensive to deploy, you may use the form functionality in Microsoft Word instead. Here's a [tip](http://word.tips.net/T000600_Saving_Form_Data_for_a_Database.html) to save data from Microsoft Word forms to the database.

Comment: Infopath would be the best for this. But my company is not going to drop the cash for that. And my users complain enough as it is about making forms in Word 2007. I guess no one has done this before...?

Comment: Check out JotForm: http://www.jotform.com/ This is not an answer to your problem but it gives you an idea what is out there.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't rate comments. This is a great starting point. Thank you!